# Getting undefined value from an array

Tags: javascript

Talk is cheap; I'd rather show the code:

```
//global var
var siblings = [];

var rand = new Date().getTime();
siblings.push('uin_' + rand);
alert(siblings['uin_' + rand]); // undefined
```

Why undefined? What I basically want to achieve is to have a global object that would be a storage where info about other objects get saved. But get back to my problem. I pushed the value then I want to alert it but get undefined... why undefined?

Comment: what value would you expect to see?

Comment: When in doubt, try using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to take a look.

Answer (score 6):

`.push` appends it to the array, `siblings[0]` contains it because it's the first element in (formerly) empty array.

If you want to  determine the key yourself, do

```
siblings = {};
siblings['key'] = 'something';
```

Otherwise loop through the array if you want to access each element

```
for ( var l = siblings.length, i = 0; i<l; ++i ) {
   alert( siblings[i] )
}
```

Note: arrays are objects so I could've set `siblings['key'] = 'something';` on the array, but that's not preferred.

Answer (score 2):

`siblings` is an array. You're pushing the value `'uin_'+rand` onto it, so the keys would then be `0`. Instead, you'd want to create an object.

```
var siblings={};
var rand=+new Date();
siblings['uin_'+rand]="something";
alert(siblings['uin_' + rand]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you pushed a string value to array index `0`, then tried to get a non-existant property on the array object.

Try using [`Array.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/pop).

Answer (score 0):

In order to access an array, you need to use array indices, which basically refer to whether you want the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.

In this case, use `siblings[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `siblings` is an array, not an associative array. Two solutions:

```
//global var - use as an array
var siblings = [];

var rand = new Date().getTime();
siblings.push('uin_' + rand);
alert(siblings[0]); // undefined

//global var - use as an associative array
var siblings = {};

var rand = new Date().getTime();
siblings.push('uin_' + rand);
alert(siblings['uin_' + rand]); // undefined
```